WinUI CommunityToolkit: Add TokenizingTextBox to Settingscard or SettingsCard Item
is there a way to combine TokenizingTextBox with SettingsCard? If I will do that, my application crash instantly.
This is what I tried in my XAML file:
xmlns:labs="using:CommunityToolkit.Labs.WinUI"
xmlns:controls="using:CommunityToolkit.WinUI.UI.Controls"

 <labs:SettingsCard Header="Title">
     <labs:SettingsCard.HeaderIcon>
         <FontIcon Glyph="&#xE97C;" />
     </labs:SettingsCard.HeaderIcon>
     <controls:TokenizingTextBox  PlaceholderText="Add Tags" />
 </labs:SettingsCard>

Got an crash.

Is that not possible? If I remove the TokenizingTextBox, the page is loading.
Thanks for your help.

BTW, SettingsCard is officially released. You don't need to use it from the Labs. You can find it as CommunityToolkit.WinUI.Controls.TokenizingTextBox NuGet package.

I will check that, thanks

Have you tried setting its Width or MaxWidth?
<toolkit:SettingsCard>
    <toolkit:TokenizingTextBox MaxWidth="1000" />
</toolkit:SettingsCard>


Thats the problem. Thank you very much :)
